# Objective-C Blocks and Garbage Collection Enviroment

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection, objective-c-blocks

I can't found any reference about Blocks and Garbage Collection; even the "Apple Bocks Reference" doesn't mention anithing about it (just few notes).

I never developed using blocks in a GC enviroment and I would like to know how it works, what is supported and how much "automatic" is the whole process.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use GC -- use ARC instead. It's almost as simple to program as GC, but it performs better because it's a compile-time feature (rather than run-time).

Comment: I only develop for iOS so GC is not my target.

Unfortunately I need to produce some documentation about Blocks and GC for an outsourced job, so I need some detailed informations.

Answer (score 0):

As an implementation optimisation blocks are initially stack allocated; this means you can pass them down the stack without issue.

However should you wish to pass them up the stack (as return values) or store them they must first be copied to the heap. Once on the heap normal memory management rules apply, whether you are using MRC, GC or ARC - so they work fine under GC.

To copy them onto the heap you must use block_copy() (or [ copy]) if you are using GC or MRC; under ARC *provided* you don't cast away the type (e.g. by assigning to a variable of type `id`) then the block_copy is automatic when storing into a strong variable or returning from a function - but calling it causes no harm so if in doubt you can call it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason Garbage Collection isn't discussed in newer documentation, and it isn't that Garbage Collection is too new.

Watch WWDC 2012 session 101, from 1:13:00—1:14:10. This session is under NDA, but you will not use Garbage Collection after watching 70 seconds of that session. (And I'll update this answer once the details go public, which they should when Mountain Lion ships.)

Also, see [Chris Lattner's post here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/146583?start=0&tstart=0). Chris Lattner works for Apple, and posted this before WWDC.

Bottom line:

1. Don't use garbage collection.
2. If you're using garbage collection, you'll want to migrate once Xcode 4.4 comes out.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I'll wait your answer once ML will be released.

Comment: from session 101 we can understand that Garbage Collection will be deprecated from 10.8 on.. interesting news.

Comment: Shh, shh. NDA means no public discussion. Probably for less than a month now. :)